# Unable to create Actual tools in workorder

Tags: maximo-anywhere

Hi I am not able to add actual tools in Maximo Anywhere work execution app. I am getting below error :-
Logger.js:326 2019-01-08, 06:36:59.730[ERROR] [ERROR]Error: Failed to set the 'ed98af739ccb7bf61380e39dea7ca67ad15991af_workOrder' property on 'Storage': Setting the value of 'ed98af739ccb7bf61380e39dea7ca67ad15991af_workOrder' exceeded the quota.
    at Object._setData (http://cwa100723d:10080/MaximoAnywhere/apps/services/preview/WorkExecution/android/7.6.3/default/js/platform/store/internal/LocalStorageCollection.js:96:33)
    at Object._storeInLocalStorage (http://cwa100723d:10080/MaximoAnywhere/apps/services/preview/WorkExecution/android/7.6.3/default/js/platform/store/internal/LocalStorageCollection.js:359:9)
    at Object.replace (http://cwa100723d:10080/MaximoAnywhere/apps/services/preview/WorkExecution/android/7.6.3/default/js/platform/store/internal/LocalStorageCollection.js:286:11)
    at Object. (http://cwa100723d:10080/MaximoAnywhere/apps/services/preview/WorkExecution/android/7.6.3/default/js/platform/store/PersistenceManager.js:876:49)

Has anybody found same issue

Comment: What version of Anywhere are you running? This looks like an issue with the space when attempting to save a record, does this happen with every transaction?

Comment: no other records are find its only with actual tools transaction we are on 763 version.

Comment: I don't have an 7.6.3 environment, so I'm shooting from the hip here. In Anywhere 7.6, the _setData function is where this is bombing. You may be able to add a breakpoint in that function and look at the data that it's trying to write to the localstore.